# SQL Server bcp utility export/write incomplete data

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp, sqlbulkcopy

I am using [SQL Server bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to export data in csv format from a table.
I've noticed that sometimes the exported data is incomplete, I mean the bcp process exit without errors but the resulting csv file shows incomplete data at the end.

For example this is the bcp command and log of a recent export:

```
bcp "SELECT IdSap, CodSap, replace(replace(convert(nvarchar(max), Dati_XML), char(13), ''), char(10), '') as Dati_XML FROM MYDB.dbo.MyTable WHERE DataAggiornamento > '2019-06-07'" queryout "C:\temp\bcp_output.csv" -c -t 0x1f -U "myuser" -P "mypassword" -S "10.180.188.53"
```

[image]

As you can see there are no errors. The output file shows 100885 rows. The problem here is that the query should return 292887 rows, not 100884. It's like the bcp process has not finished to properly import/write data before exit.

Does anyone know why is this happening and any possible fix?

Comment: You haven't posted what you tried (ie the command line) or what the CSV looks like. Are there 100884 rows in the file?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've updated the question. The file shows 100885 rows, the last row is truncated.

Comment: Where's that last row? Don't force people to guess. BTW `NOLOCK` means "read dirty data while taking excessive locks". Remove it. It *can* cause a query to fail if the data is being modified at that moment.

Comment: Furthermore, the attempt to replace newlines in a field called `Dati_XML` suggests you're trying to export XML data. Perhaps the problem is the data itself, especially if that field contains newlines. Again, you need to post an example of that file.

Comment: That is a replacement of \n and \r characters to have a properly csv in output. The NOLOCK is not relevant here, since I saw this problem happening even without it (removed it from the query). The key problem here is that the bcp process exited (with no errors) without having imported all the data: it shows 100884 rows imported, but a SELECT COUNT(*) of the same query shows that the rows imported should be 292887.

Comment: Have you inspected the exported file? Are the rows that do make it into the file formatted properly? Also, just for fun, have you tried using a different row terminator? Last, how are you getting a "csv" file without specifying a terminator? The default for SQL will be the TAB character.

Comment: @jamie The separator is specified, it's the unit separator 0x1f. The rows are formatted properly except for the last one which is truncated. But again the problem here is that bcp command didn't import all data it was supposed to fetch from the database, exiting with an exit status = 0 thus without notifying any errors. It seems a very dangerous behavior for an import/export data utility

Comment: I highly, highly doubt that BCP did anything incorrect here. Most likely there is something else going on - there is not going to be anything to fix in BCP, rather we'll find something wrong with the data (and how you are choosing to delimit data) or the data itself isn't what you think it is. Or mixup in servers... query getting the count running on one server (prod) and the bcp from another (test)... it happens... jus sayin :)

Comment: I think if you first turn suspicion away from an executable that has been around for decades and instead inspect all the things you thought you knew, you will find something (at least... I always do :)

Comment: A couple of things to make clear, just to see if anything comes up... I asked if you tried a different row terminator, but I meant to say column delimiter. Yes, I see you are using 0x1f, but why? that is a very odd field terminator. Add to that, you are extracting out to a file with the suffix ".csv"... but no commas are used to delimit data? can you share why? just curious. Just in case the 0x1f character actually exist already IN your data, can you try a different field delimiter? "~" or "|"? just for fun?

Comment: try putting the results of the query into a table with "select into".. the check those results and also bcp that new table out... any difference?

Comment: nvarcharmax is another suspect, imho. When you select the data, can you convert out of nvarcharmax into something like varchar(8000), or just trim it down, just to test, and elimninate nvarcharmax? Just some ideas to try to isolate.

Comment: @jamie Thanks for the suggestions. The data has a very long xml column with data coming from websites etc, thus any common human typing character is likely to be present in the data, that's why I am using the unit separator 0x1f which seems less likely to be present (at least for now). But regardless of the separator, bcp terminated with a count of 100884 rows fetched, which is not by far the number of rows expected (292887). Is it possible that the bcp import was terminated on server side by some admin or other high priority process?

Comment: "terminated on server side" this should be easily tested. Just run it again. and again. you keep getting the same rows? then likely not due to unexpected termination. Also, you can try killing your own bcp connection (be sure it is your connection!) and see how BCP responds.